# Is $1/(T-t)$ an almost everywhere finite function for $t\in[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

**Context:**

I'm reading theorem which requires me to check the following conditions:

> Let the vector valued function $f(t,x)$ be defined almost everywhere and measurable in the domain $G$ of the $(t,x)$-space ($t\in[0,\infty), x\in\mathbb{R}^n$) and let there exists, for each bounded closed domain $D\subset G$, an almost everywhere finite function $m(t)$ such that
> $$
> |f(t,x)|\leq m(t)
> $$
> almost everywhere in $D$.

and the theorem continues with some conclusions on $f(t,x)$ and other objects arising from it, which I omit here since those are not important for this question. However, I wan't to use that theorem for the following $f(t,x)$:
$$
f(t,x) = \frac{x}{T-t}
$$
with $n=1,G=\mathbb{R}, T>0$. So I need to check if my $f(t,x)$ is defined almost everywhere and measurable for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and if there exists the function $m(t)$. So, for each closed bounded domain $D\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\inf D=\underline{x}, \sup D = \overline{x}$, I proposed
$$
m(t) = \frac{\max(|\underline{x}|,|\overline{x}|)}{T-t}
$$
which verifies $|f(t,x)|\leq m(t)$. Now, I have to check that this function is almost everywhere finite (in $t$), which I believe it is, since it is finite except for $t=T$. However, I'm not entirely sure I'm missing something, or misinterpreting what "almost everywhere finite" means.

**Question:**

So, Is it correct to say that $\frac{1}{T-t}$ is almost everywhere finite in the context of the question?

Comment: Almost everywhere means outside a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Since the singleton $\{T\}$ is such a set you are done.

Comment: Nice, I just wanted to make sure I was not missing something. Thanks